# TypeScript resuse string literals?

Tags: javascript, typescript, string-literals

Is there a way to reuse string literals so I am not copy/pasting? something like this:

```
export class SendingStates {
    public static sendingStates: 'waiting' | 'sending' | 'sent' | 'error' | 'input-error'
}

interface IProps {
    sendingState: SendingStates.sendingStates
}
```

Basically, I want to have access to the 'sendingStates' type in multiple classes - thank you!

Comment: Can't you create an `AppConstants.ts` file and export JSON containing keys? Then you can import this file anywhere you want to use this constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by defining a `type`:

```
export type AVAILABLE_SENDING_STATES = 'waiting' | 'sending' | 'sent' | 'error' | 'input-error';
```

Then use it where you want as a type:

```
interface IProps {
    sendingState: AVAILABLE_SENDING_STATES
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typeof` to reuse the type:

```
export class SendingStates {
    public static sendingStates: 'waiting' | 'sending' | 'sent' | 'error' | 'input-error'
}

interface IProps {
    sendingState: typeof SendingStates.sendingStates
}
```

Or you can create a type alias:

```
type sendingStateType = 'waiting' | 'sending' | 'sent' | 'error' | 'input-error'

export class SendingStates {
    public static sendingStates: sendingStateType
}

interface IProps {
    sendingState: sendingStateType
}
```

Comment: the `type` also be exported to expose it to other files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `enum` but there's a far better way for this case called a `string literal`:

`type StringLiteral = '1st literal' | '2nd literal' | 'nth literal';`

This will give you editor autocomplete as well as compile time errors. As with all types you can export it for further reusability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enum`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

```
enum SENDING_STATES {
    WAITING = "WAITING",
    SENDING = "SENDING"
}

interface IProps {
    sendingState: SENDING_STATES
}
```